# Showing results between 5 to 14 days

Tags: if-statement, between

I am coding some customer service scripts and the aim is to show the results from 5 - 14 days after the deadline/date.

For example: date= 2016-01-20.
So five days after would be 01-25 and 14 would be 02.03 and the results should display it inbetween 5 to 14 days.

I have made an if statement:

```
if (date>= date.addDay(5) && date<= date.addDay(14))
{
print("Ticket ID: " + se.getField(0) + "\n" + "Ticket date: " + se.getField(1) + "\n\n");

}
```

functions addDay - adds a days to the date.
getField - gets fields ID and deadline/date.

In the results of this script I get also results from 2015. So there is something wrong with the logic of if-statement. 
How should How to make it display results between 5 days after deadline to 14 days after deadline.

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: Everything is greater than none... I suspect that addDay doesn't return anything.

Comment: This is a custom language of the product, company I work in is selling. but the if statement would be the same in java or other languages. Print just displays the data. addDay adds the days to the date 2016-01-20 - so if date.addDay(2) will add 2 days to 01-20 and the result will be 01-22